# How do I fade in and fade out a custom panel control in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, custom-controls

I have created a custom Panel Control as follows:

```
Namespace CustomPanelControl
Public Class CustomPanel
    Inherits Panel

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub
    Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams
        Get
            Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
            cp.ExStyle = &H20
            Return cp
        End Get
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaintBackground(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
        'do nothing here
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub Refresh()
        Parent.Invalidate(New Rectangle(Me.Location, Me.Size), True)
    End Sub

    Protected Sub InvalidateEx()
        If Parent Is Nothing Then
            Return
        End If
        Dim rc As New Rectangle(Me.Location, Me.Size)
        Parent.Invalidate(rc, True)
    End Sub
End Class
End Namespace
```

Now I need to use it and make it fade in and out.  This is a panel containing typical play, stop, FF, REW controls over a media player.  Just like Windows Player or VLC, I want the panel containing the controls to fade out on mouse leave and fade in on mouse enter.

How do I do this?  TIA!

Answer (score 2):

have a look at this: [AlphaGradientPanel From CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13558/AlphaGradientPanel-an-extended-panel)

[image: SCREENSHOT]

Answer (score 0):

Winforms doesn't have any mechanism for that.  Forms have opacity, but controls do not.

You can try *cheating* by taking a snap shot of your control using `DrawToBitmap(...)` and then placing the bitmap in a borderless, focusless form over the control area, then fade the opacity value from there.

But any solution using WinForms is going to get a bit hacky.  The standard answer here is to think about WPF or reconsider your animation requirements.